# imageView image size doesn't change

Tags: xcode, swift

I set with the help of constraints width 100, but when I run the app image covers half of the UITableViewCell and I cannot change it. What is the problem ? Why my image doesn't change the size and how can I fix it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: More info please, images, code

Comment: There could be a problem, when you set the contentMode to AspectFill, but doesn't set clip subviews. But your picture clearly indicates, that there are not enough constraints on your imageView.

Comment: @Arbitur I add an image of my storyboard. Anything else? It's just prints an image

Comment: @DánielNagy I set AspectFill and unchecked `Clip Subviews` and `Autoresize Subviews`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you want to keep its height=width=103 ?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade check clip subviews. Or set the content mode to aspect fit.

Comment: @RoNiT yes. Height is equal to row height with the margins 8 from top, bottom, left and width: 103

Comment: @DánielNagy nothing. The same thing

Comment: There are some orange lines in your storyboard something else might cause the problem

Comment: @Arbitur it's constraint(vertically center) and width constraints

Comment: But do you have a x position constraint?

Comment: @Arbitur x position is?

Comment: Give us every constraint that is currently on that image. The ones we know atm is centerY and width, you need an x constraint aswell.

Comment: Easiest would be to screenshot Size inspector.

Comment: @Arbitur I added it too to the question

Comment: You dont need the top space when you have a height and y position. I dont think that is the troublemaker but its unnecessary.

Comment: Are you dequeuing the correct cell in your table view controller? Make sure that the cell identifier in Interface Builder and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` match.

Answer (score 0):

Set this constraints, this will keep it away 8 pixels from left and top with height=width=103 :[image]

Comment: also set your content type is Aspect Fit

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have added proper constrains to your UITableView too, if your TableView is imbedded in your ViewController. Please, ignore this, if you are using UITableViewController directly.Assuming, you are having the Tableview inside a ViewController, add this constrain and uncheck the "Constrain to margin".

[image]

2. Then add the following constrain and also uncheck the "Constrain to margin".

[image]

Hope, this works.

Comment: Nope... I do not know what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Check the identity inspector (3rd option) and "view mode". Try changing it to aspect fit or scale to fill.

Different, hard way:
You can also programatically change size of the picture:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```